# PHP Count of XML Nodes

Tags: php, xml

I have a dynamic XML block that I am running some PHP against.

In short, it counts all of the departments per area and if there are more than 5 departments, I list out the area names. If there are less than 5 departments, I list out the department names.

Here is the block of XML I am working with:

```
<impactOptions>
  <opsAreaImpact>
    <areas>
      <area>
        <area>Main Area 1</area>
        <departments>
          <department>Test 1</department>
          <department>Test 2</department>
        </departments>
      </area>
      <area>
        <area>Main Area 2</area>
        <departments>
          <department>Another Test 1</department>
          <department>Another Test 2</department>
          <department>Another Test 3</department>
          <department>Another Test 4</department>
          <department>Another Test 5</department>
        </departments>
      </area>
      <area>
        <area>Main Area 3</area>
        <departments>
          <department>Final Test 1</department>
        </departments>
      </area>
    </areas>
  </opsAreaImpact>
 </impactOptions>
```

Here is my PHP code that I am using for this operation:

```
if ($data->impactOptions->opsAreaImpact)
    {
    $opsArea = $data->impactOptions->opsAreaImpact;
    $first = true;
    $locationCount = $opsArea->areas->area->departments->department->count();
    if ($locationCount > 5)
        {
        foreach($opsArea->areas->area as $area)
            {
            if (!$first)
                {
                echo ', ';
                }

            echo $area->area;
            $first = false;
            }
        }
      else
        {
        foreach($opsArea->areas->area->departments->department as $department)
            {
            if (!$first)
                {
                echo ', ';
                }

            echo $department;
            $first = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue I am running into is its only getting the count of departments for the first node it see's; not all of them. For example the count in this example would be 2 as the first area block has 2 departments. However the expected outcome should be 8 because in all of the area blocks, there are a total of 8 departments.

Is there a way I can count those nodes recursively and not just stop after the first one?

The result for this example SHOULD be: `Main Area 1, Main Area 2, Main Area 3` because the total number of departments is greater than 5. If it were less than 5, it would list out the department names instead.

Answer (score 0):

[**XPath**](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) is your friend in this case when you want to do these kind of selections. Think of it similar to the JQuery selectors.

Let's break down a bit the XPath queries used:

- `//areas//department` - the first XPath query basically says: find
  all `departments` that are descendant of the `areas` element, no
  matter where they are under the `areas` element.
- `//areas/area/area` - after we established the amount of departments, we have a choice: list all the departments in which case we already have them, or show the areas ergo this query. The XPath query translates to: give me all the `area` elements that are a direct descendant of an `area` element who is a direct descendant of the `areas` element.

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadXML(file_get_contents('test.xml'));

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// give me all the departments 
$query = '//areas//department';
$departments = $xpath->query($query);

// more than 5 so list the area names
if ($departments->length > 5) {
    $query = '//areas/area/area';
    $areas = $xpath->query($query);

    foreach ($areas as $area) {
        echo $area->nodeValue;
    }
// less than 5 so list out the department names
} else {
    foreach ($departments as $department) {
        echo $department->nodeValue;
    }
}
```